# Mosaic with LISS-III RESOURCESAT-1 images

Tags: qgis, satellite, image-mosaic

[image]

I'm having problems with dark edges in normal or virtual catalog (.vrt) with LISIII LISS-III RESOURCESAT-1 mosaic. If I put no data value 0 in properties, change border by white (see figure) and I want a superposition between satellite images in my final geoTif image. Can someone help me?

My code:

```
gdalbuildvrt "C:/Users/ASANTOS/Dropbox/GIS_formiga_Arnhold/Data analysis/test.vrt" "C:/Users/ASANTOS/Dropbox/GIS_formiga_Arnhold/Data analysis/P6_LIS3_20120311_324_100_L2_BAND2_FINAL.tif" "C:/Users/ASANTOS/Dropbox/GIS_formiga_Arnhold/Data analysis/P6_LIS3_20120316_325_100_L2_BAND2_FINAL.tif"
```